# Inserting icon into context menu using shell extension

Tags: python, windows, shell, winapi, pywin32

I'm making a Windows shell extension, using pywin32, and I'm adding a right-click context menu item via `QueryContextMenu`. I'm attempting to insert a system icon from `imageres.dll` along with it. I'm essentially trying to do it using `ExtractIconEx` and `GetIconInfo`:

```
def QueryContextMenu(self, hMenu, indexMenu, idCmdFirst, idCmdLast, uFlags):

        # ... Some other code ...

        item_text = 'New context menu entry'

        large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(r'C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll', 202)
        bitmap = win32gui.GetIconInfo(small[0])[4]

        item, extras = win32gui_struct.PackMENUITEMINFO(text=item_text,
                                                        hbmpItem=bitmap,
                                                        wID=idCmdFirst)

        win32gui.InsertMenuItem(hMenu, indexMenu+1, 1, item)

        return 1
```

This code doesn't throw any errors, but the icon is not displayed, and the command is ultimately not invoked either. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: `InsertMenu()` is long deprecated, you should be using `InsertMenuItem()` instead, which allows you to set both text and bitmap in a single function call

Comment: Thank you very much.  I guess I was working from an out-of-date sample.  I'll try to implement with InsertMenuItem() and see if I have any more success.

Comment: I now changed it to InsertMenuItem(), but it's still not working.

Comment: Using InsertMenu and then setting the bitmap is the same as using InsertMenuItem, the item will act the same way when the menu is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I made the change in response to Remy Lebeau's comment, but my underlying question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is the icon then you can just create a normal static registry menu item and set the Icon value in the registry. That will work on Windows 7 and later and there is no need to create a shell extension. On older versions you do have to create a shell extension if you want a icon.

On Vista you can [convert the icon to a 32-bit ARGB bitmap](http://web.archive.org/web/20080121112802/http://shellrevealed.com/blogs/shellblog/archive/2007/02/06/Vista-Style-Menus_2C00_-Part-1-_2D00_-Adding-icons-to-standard-menus.aspx) and set it as the menu item bitmap.

On XP and older you should use [HBMMENU_CALLBACK](https://www.nanoant.com/programming/themed-menus-icons-a-complete-vista-xp-solution) or custom draw.

Just using a plain bitmap has transparency issues. Windows 95 and NT4? do not support the plain bitmap method and using the checked/unchecked bitmaps has both size and transparency issues.

Comment: Thanks, but my extension contains more logic.  I simplified things for purposes of the question.

Comment: The ARGB bitmap method is valid on 7 and later as well.